# Android: Display date from DatePickerDialogFragment in another fragment

Tags: android

I have implemented `DatePickerDialogFragment` that is shown after clcik on `ActionBar` menu. item. I was following android developers example http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html Now I need display date in another `fragment` (I'm using `NavigationDrawer` in MainActivity). I have tried put data into `bundle` in `onDateSet` method but when I tried to get data in fragment it ends with NPE. Please can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you I appreciate every help.

Answer (score 0):

lets say you keep a static Date variable in the parent activity, when date is picked save the date picked in the static variable with the getActivity() method, and then switch fragments.

then in the onViewCreated method of the second fragment just init the datepicker with the date value in the parent activty.